# How to emulate a version of OpenGL higher than the one your gpu supports?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, gaming, opengl, emulation

Ok so there is a certain game i want to play. when it comes to the requirements, the game is pretty light, the only thing that is preventing me from running the game is my old gpu that doesn't support OpenGL 3, after searching for a while i came across someone talking about the possibility of emulating OpenGL 3, but i didn't get an explanation of how to do it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

For more specific information, I need OpenGL 3.3 to run the game and the game is called 5d chess with multiverse time travel.

Also I'm new to stack exchange so if I'm asking this question in the wrong place, please redirect me to the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is part software, but also part hardware, so if your card cannot do it, it cannot do it.

On the upside, Open GL 3.3 is from 2010, so pretty much any GPU built since then can run it. That's the kind of thing you could find in a junk shop these days, for just a few $£€.

If you are running an older OS & older drivers, it would always be wise to check for latest drivers, in case the card is capable, but the drivers are not.